# What does the "Access IBM" button do on old IBM laptops?

Tags: thinkpad

What does the "Access IBM" button do on old IBM laptops?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVcTq.jpg]

What is the function of this key?

Comment: Press it, I dare you...

Comment: Why didn't you look it up in the manual?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### What is the function of this key?

It provides access to IBM specific system utilities and information.

> The ThinkPad Button is a button situated in the upper left corner of
> the keyboard on modern ThinkPads. It is intended to be a means of
> quick access to help and support. Technically it is nothing else than
> a button that can be configured to launch a certain piece of software.
> While originally it was grey and labelled <kbd>ThinkPad</kbd>, IBM
> later made it blue and called it the <kbd>Access IBM</kbd> Button.
> Lenovo relabelled it as <kbd>ThinkVantage</kbd> after it took over the
> ThinkPad line from IBM.

Source [ThinkPad Button - ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkPad_Button)

> An Access IBM button is conveniently located on many IBM keyboards to
> provide one-touch access to the IBM on-system utilities and
> information.
>
> Hierarchical organization of the software simplifies access to a
> universe of information and function specific to ThinkPad notebooks or
> ThinkCentre desktops.
>
> This helps individuals set up, learn, and better use their systems.
> Access IBM is available on ThinkPad notebooks through one touch of the
> dedicated hardware button, and on both ThinkPad notebooks and
> ThinkCentre desktops through the Start menu and a desktop icon to
> accommodate multiple preferences.
>
> ...
>
> Access IBM includes unique onboard utilities and self-help tools to
> assist with key tasks and resolution of common system problems. The
> tools are machine-specific and designed to help save time and reduce
> the organization’s user-support burden.

Source [ThinkPad_comfort.pdf](https://www-03.ibm.com/able/accessibility_services/ThinkPad_comfort.pdf)

It was used, for example, to perform an OS recovery.

> **How to Restore the IBM ThinkPad T42**
>
> Restart the computer and press the "Access IBM" button above the top
> row of keys on your keyboard when you first see the IBM logo screen.
> The correct button on your keyboard depends on the model ThinkPad you
> own.
>
> Press the down-arrow key to move the cursor to the "ThinkPad Product
> Recovery Program" option and press the "Enter" key. Once the "ThinkPad
> Recovery Menu" appears, press the "F11" key to start the recovery and
> restore process.
>
> Follow the on-screen prompts to restore the ThinkPad T42's hardware
> settings and software to factory defaults. When prompted to do so,
> press any key on the keyboard to restart the laptop. Allow the
> recovery process to finish and wait for the computer to boot into
> Windows.

Source [How to Restore the IBM ThinkPad T42 | It Still Works | Giving Old Tech a New Life](https://itstillworks.com/restore-ibm-thinkpad-t42-6916708.html)

Comment: So it doesn't instantly hack into IBM then? :(

Comment: Please note that the special key on startup only does special things if you never removed the recovery partition from the harddrive. It forces the bios to boot into the recovery partition in stead of the normal OS. If there is no recovery partition it (on most models I encountered) acts as an extra Enter key.